# Не отображаются русские символы при создании объекта

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Добрый день

rails 3.2

ruby 2.0

есть форма для создания или редактирования опроса:

```
= f.error_messages header_message: nil
= f.input :question, input_html: { class: 'input-block-level' }
= f.input :results_hidden, as: :boolean, inline_label: 'Скрыть результаты до окончания опроса', label: false
= f.input :from_date, as: :datetime, input_html: { class: 'poll_date' }
= f.input :to_date, as: :datetime, input_html: { class: 'poll_date' }
%h3#poll-items Варианты ответа (не больше пяти)
.item_index  
  = f.fields_for :poll_items do |poll|
    = render "poll_item_fields", f: poll
  .links
    = link_to_add_association 'Добавить еще вариант', f, :poll_items, render_options: {class: 'links'}
```

**polls_controller.rb**

```
def update
    if @poll.owner_type == "Post"
      @post = Post.find(@poll.owner_id)
    elsif @poll.owner_type == "BlogPost"  
      @post = BlogPost.find(@poll.owner_id)
    end

    binding.pry
    if @poll.editable?(current_user)
      if @poll.update_attributes params[:poll]
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Опрос был успешно обновлен.' }
        end
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render :edit, alert: @poll.errors }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

При создании или редактирования опроса в статье, русские символы отображаются в виде ??????????

Если я создаю новую статью , все отображается кирилицей. Проблема только в создании или редактировании Poll(опроса).

Установлен гем "russian".

database.yml имеет кодировку utf8

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MySQL driver:
#   gem install mysql2
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db_development
  username: root
  password: "123" 
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНО:**
я зашел через консоль в админку mysql. сделал запрос: SELECT * FROM polls WHERE id = 13;

question: ?????3

Comment: зашел через rails console, аналогично.  #<Poll id: 13, question: "?????3",

Comment: я зашел через консоль в админку mysql. сделал запрос: SELECT * FROM polls WHERE id = 13;  question: ?????3

Comment: То есть, в базе таки неправильные данные. Значит, надо проверять их путь до базы. Смотреть в отладчике содержимое формы `create` в процессе сохранения, смотреть совершаемые к базе запросы в логах, смотреть настройки базы.

Comment: Да, но почему то другие объекты приложения создаются по русски. статьи и т.д.

Comment: А вот это, скорее всего, вам может сказать только отладчик.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с encode. Вам нужно поставить необходимый encode. Не знаю, можно ли менять в мускуле это без удаления таблицы. Нашел вот это на просторах интернета:

***WARNING Это удалит содержимое вашей таблицы***

```
$ mysql -u USER -p
mysql > drop database YOURDB_NAME_development;
mysql > create database YOURDB_NAME_development CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
mysql > \q
$ rake db:migrate
```

Источник [тут](http://extazystas.ru/mysql2-encoding-solving/)